# Drivers for TrekStor Surftab Xiron 7.0 3G

Tags: tablet, usb-debugging

I just bought a TrekStor Surftab Xiron 7.0, and I was trying to use it to test apps. It's the first time I do this, so maybe I'm just doing something wrong.
I turned on the developer settings and the USB debug, connected the tablet to the computer and tried to install the Google drivers (The ones in the SDK), it didn't work. Then I tried to search for drivers on the TrekStor website, but they don't seem to have download links. I tried another couple of drivers I found online, but none of them worked.

Does anybody know where I can find working drivers? The Android version is 4.2.2 (Jelly Bean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem!
You have to add the vendor-id to adb_usb.ini !

> echo 0x1e68 >> $HOME/.android/adb_usb.ini

source:
https://urbanjack.wordpress.com/2014/10/23/howto-use-surftab-xiron-on-mac-for-development-adb/